# How to return index of ranges in listbox after they've been transferred from another in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, listbox

I'm working with an array of values, some of which's main names (column A) are the same and differentiated by an additional designation (column B). In this, it's first (text) and first (sub), which is how they've been entered into the left ListBox and then one has been transferred to the right. Once the values have been selected and transferred to the right ListBox. I want to be able to press Go and run operations on row 2 because that is where the value in the right ListBox is located. How do I return the index, (or even just the row number), of the selected items? I intend for the finished version of this to operate on a varying number of items that will be placed in the right ListBox, so I need to be able to have a dynamic number of indexes from which to operate on.

[image: What I've got]

```
'This is how I've added the entries manually so far. I intend to add them as a dynamic array in the future.

    Dim RMs(1 To 3) As String

        RMs(1) = Range("A1").Value
        RMs(2) = Range("A2").Value
        RMs(3) = Range("A3").Value

    Dim List(1 To 3) As String

        List(1) = RMs(1) & " (" & Range("B1").Value & ")"
        List(2) = RMs(2) & " (" & Range("B2").Value & ")"
        List(3) = RMs(3) & " (" & Range("B3").Value & ")"

     With Sheet1.ListBox1
        .AddItem List(1)
        .AddItem List(2)
        .AddItem List(3)
    End With
```

Comment: Just did! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% about what you are after, but maybe you can get some idea's (if I'm not completely wrong)

---

To load `ListBox1` with a dynamic range, you could try:

```
Sub LoadLB1()

Dim arr As Variant, lr As Long, x As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    .ListBox1.Clear
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:B" & lr)
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        .ListBox1.AddItem arr(x, 1) & "," & arr(x, 2)
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

You noticed I seperated the main names with the designation through a comma. This could come in handy in the second part below.

---

When you populated `ListBox2` and you want to loop through all listitems of `ListBox2` you may try:

```
Sub GetRowLB2()

Dim arr As Variant, lr As Long, x As Long, rw As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 0 To .ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        arr = Split(.ListBox2.List(x), ",")
        rw = .Evaluate("MATCH(1,(A1:A" & lr & "=""" & arr(0) & """)*(B1:B" & lr & "=""" & arr(1) & """),0)")
        Debug.Print rw 'Or do some other calculations on this row
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

You can now see why the comma came in handy as we could do a simple `Split`.

---

Again, not sure if this is what you are after. Also some notes on this code, the `MATCH` will throw an error if for some reason your data does NOT include the main value and designation combination.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand the gist of what you're doing! The first part creates the array of all values thru A and B and pastes the actual values into listbox1 using the first, second format instead of my format of first (second), which makes a lot of sense given the split function you've used (and one I can adapt going forward).  The second returns the row of each individual item when it's moved over, which is what I need. I'm hoping you tell me how this returns the row though:

 
rw = .Evaluate("MATCH(1,(A1:A" & lr & "=""" & arr(0) & """)*(B1:B" & lr & "=""" & arr(1) & """),0)")

Comment: I'm simulating a worksheet match function. Add a line: 'Debug.Print "MATCH(1,(A1:A" & lr & "=""" & arr(0) & """)*(B1:B" & lr & "=""" & arr(1) & """),0)"'. You'll notice it's actually a very logical formula that takes the two criteria and returns the correct row. Evaluate just makes that happen in VBA. I hope it makes sense :S @Poppenhoffer

Comment: So I just threw it in there and the syntax of that line isn't working, but there's so much going on in there I can't figure out why.

Comment: @Poppenhoffer, best thing to do in that case (I can't see what you doing exactly) is to recreate the simple sample data you put in the question. And put the `Listbox`s in the sheet and go from there. Once you got it working on such simple sample data you can extend it to suit your needs. I tried the code, and it works fine on my end.

Comment: After some testing, I keep getting a type mismatch and it seems to stem from the 1 in Match(1, ...)

Comment: Actually it appears to work. My system just doesn't want to print the rw variable for some reason but after having it paste to another cell I'm getting the values. Thanks!

Comment: @poppenhoffer, glad it helped. If so, consider to mark as accepter answer to return the favor